# Maschke's theorem fails when $p||G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $p$ a prime which divides $|G|$. Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Let $\epsilon\in F[G]$ - the group algebra - be the sum all elements of $G$.

> How to show that the $F[G]$-submodule $F[G]\epsilon$ is not a direct summand of $F[G]$?

The only thing I realize is that in this case $F[G]\epsilon$ is a submodule of the augmentation - the module spanned by elements $\Sigma a_gg$ where $\Sigma a_g=0$. Is this relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $FG\epsilon$ is one-dimensional, spanned by $\epsilon$.  As a $FG$-module it is iso to the trivial module.

Suppose $FG\epsilon$ were a direct summand.  Then the projection onto that summand would be a module homomorphism $\pi : FG \to FG\epsilon$ with kernel not containing $FG\epsilon$.  But if $\pi : FG \to FG\epsilon$ is any module map, I claim $\ker \pi$ contains $\epsilon$ and hence $FG\epsilon$.  This is because $\pi(g) = g \pi(1) = \pi(1)$ as $G$ acts trivially on $FG\epsilon$, so $\pi(\epsilon)= \sum_{g \in G} \pi(1) = |G|\pi(1) = 0$.