# Prove a simple module must be "trivial"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, p-groups

Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group, i.e. $|P|=p^n$ for some prime $p$. Let $F$ be a finite field of $p$ elements. Show that every simple $FP$-module *trivial*, where $FP$ is a group ring (which is actually a division ring because $F$ is a field).

> **Definition:** A *trivial $FP$-module* is a one dimensional $F$-vector space where all elements of $G$ acts as identity.

My attempt:

Let $M$ be a simple $FP$-module.

I know $M$ is simple if and only if it can be generated by every non-zero element, i.e. $\forall 0\neq\alpha\in M$, $M=(FP)\alpha$.

If $M$ is a one dimensional $F$-vector space, then we are done. So, we may assume $M$ is not a one dimensional $F$-vector space, which implies there exists some $e_G\neq g\in G$ and some $m\in M$ such that $g\cdot m\neq m$. We want to construct a non-zero proper submodule of $M$, which will contradict with the simplicity of $M$ and then we are done. To this end, I consider the cyclic module $(FP)(g\cdot m)$ as the condition suggests. And I found that $FP=FP(g^{-1})$, which leads to $(FP)(g\cdot m)=[FP(g^{-1})](g\cdot m)=FP[(g^{-1})(g\cdot m)]=FP(e_G\cdot m)=FP(m)$. But then I just get stuck here. I didn't (and didn't know how to) use the conditions that $|P|=p^n$, $|F|=p$ and $g\cdot m\neq m$.

My question is how to use these conditions to show that $FP(m)$ is a non-zero proper submodule of $M$? Or alternatively, can we use other ways to find a a non-zero proper submodule of $M$?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Would this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425604/maschkes-theorem-fails-when-pg ?

Comment: @NickyHekster Thanks for the link but it is somewhat different.

Comment: "If $M$ is a one dimensional $F$-vector space, then we are done" not so fast! You need to show every element acts as the identity.  That wouldn't be true without $P$ being a $p$-group

Comment: "where  is a group ring (which is actually a division ring because  is a field)." This is false unless $|P|=1$. Group rings are never division rings except in very trivial cases.

Comment: @rschwieb True. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes. I was intending to say if $M$ is trivial then we are done. And then work on the negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general fact that is useful to know. Say $|P| = p^n$ with $p$ prime, and let $F$ be a finite field with $p$ elements.

> Lemma: If $V$ is a nonzero finite-dimensional $F[P]$-module, then $P$ has a nonzero fixed point in $V$. (Meaning there exists $v \neq 0$ in $V$ such that $gv = v$ for all $g \in P$.)

To prove this lemma, look at the orbits of $P$ on $V$.

In the case where $V$ is irreducible, the result you want to prove follows from the lemma.

Comment: I have come up with a proof using an assumption that $p |\, |V|$, where $|V|$ is the cardinality of $V$. Is this assumption true?

Comment: @SamWong: If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, then $|V| = p^d$, where $d = \dim V$.

Comment: Cool. I understand your answer now as well. Thanks spin!

Answer (score 2):

It's well known that for a field of characteristic $p>0$ and a finite $p$-group $G$, the group ring $F[G]$ is local (For example "D. Passman: The algebraic structure of group rings", Lemma 1.6 of Chapter 3, page 70).) So, there is only one isoclass of simple module, and its just $F[G]/\omega(F[G])$, the quotient of by the augmentation ideal.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks rschwieb!

Comment: I accepted @spin ’s answer just because he answered a bit earlier than you (not sure if this is the convention on this site) but your answer also helped me a lot, really. Thanks again rschwieb.

Comment: @SamWong *not sure if this is the convention on this site* No, simply answering earlier is not considered a major contributor to acceptance of an answer.  You should accept whichever answer you think is better, period, even if it comes in later.  That said, I'm not saying you should change your acceptance now. I'm just saying you should not harbor undue bias for early responders going forward.

Comment: Sure. Will notice this next time. Thanks.